# get the program to recognize if its an integers or a real numbers (python)

Tags: python

thankyou for your help.

i am very new to programming, but have decided to learn Python. i am doing a program that can check if a number is a prime. this is mathematically done by checking if  (x-1)^p -(x^p-1) is devisible by p (Capable of being divided, with no remainder) then p is a prime.

However i have run into trouble. this is my code so far:

```
from sympy import *
x=symbols('x')

p=11
f=(pow(x - 1, p)) - (pow(x, p) - 1)  # (x-1)^p -(x^p-1)
f1=expand(f) 
>>> -11*x**10 + 55*x**9 - 165*x**8 + 330*x**7 - 462*x**6 + 462*x**5 -   330*x**4 + 165*x**3 - 55*x**2 + 11*x

f2= f1/p
>>> -x**10 + 5*x**9 - 15*x**8 + 30*x**7 - 42*x**6 + 42*x**5 - 30*x**4 + 15*x**3 - 5*x**2 + x
```

to tell if the number p is a prime i need to check if the coefficients of the polynomium is divisible by p. so i have to check if the coefficients of f2 is whole numbers or real numbers.

this is what i would like to make a program that can check: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvMSRWTE2mI

i have tried making it into int but it still shows fractions like 1/2 and 3/7. i wish that it will only show whole numbers.

how do i make it so?

Comment: Are you wanting a round up or round down of the result? round() is your friend.

Comment: thankyou!       no. the idear is to check if a number is a prime. this is mathematically done by checking if (x-1)^p -(x^p-1) is divisible (Capable of being divided, especially with no remainder) by p. does that make sense??

Comment: the result of the division is not important. what matters is if the result is a whole number meaning that (x-1)^p -(x^p-1) was devisible. otherwise if its not a whole number (x-1)^p -(x^p-1) was not devisible and there for not a prime.

Comment: no p is the number that is tested for primality. no i mean (x^p) - 1. this is what i am trying to do a program on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvMSRWTE2mI            i tried the % but it does not tell me if the coeficients are all whole numbers.    example: if we test the prime 11 : this is the polynomium that i get when devided by p: -x**10 + 5*x**9 - 15*x**8 + 30*x**7 - 42*x**6 + 42*x**5 - 30*x**4 + 15*x**3 - 5*x**2 + x. i would like if my program could tell if the coeficients are whole numbers.

Comment: is that posible in any way?

Comment: thankyou very much i will

Comment: that is very naive way to implement the AKS test, you get better result implementing the pascal triangle to get the coefficients directly as show by @Reti43, even soo that is still very naive, in that same video in the description they put the paper with the correct algorithm, using that and the wikipedia entry of that algorithm, I implement it some time ago, but I find it too slow (maybe I do it wrong?) so I do and use instead the Baillie-PSW test, the one they speak in the previous video

Answer (score 1):

What the method effective does is expand the polynomial and drop the first (x^p) and last coefficients (x^0). Then you have to iterate through the rest and check for divisibility. Since a polynomial expansion of power p produces p+1 terms (from 0 to p), we want to collect p-2 terms (from 1 to p-1). This is all summed up in the following code.

```
from sympy.abc import x

def is_prime_sympy(p):
    poly = pow((x - 1), p).expand()
    return not any(poly.coeff(x, i) % p for i in xrange(1, p))
```

This works, but the higher the number you input, e.g. 1013, the longer you'll notice it takes. Sympy is slow because internally it stores all expressions as some classes and all multiplications and additions take a long time. We can simply generate the coefficients using Pascal's triangle. For the polynomial (x - 1)^p, the coefficients are supposed to change sign, but we don't care about that. We just want the raw numbers. Credits to Copperfield for pointing out you only need half of the coefficients because of symmetry.

```
import math

def combination(n, r):
    return math.factorial(n) // (math.factorial(r) * math.factorial(n - r))

def pascals_triangle(row):
    # only generate half of the coefficients because of symmetry
    return (combination(row, term) for term in xrange(1, (row+1)//2))

def is_prime_math(p):
    return not any(c % p for c in pascals_triangle(p))
```

We can time both methods now to see which one is faster.

```
import time

def benchmark(p):
    t0 = time.time()
    is_prime_math(p)
    t1 = time.time()
    is_prime_sympy(p)
    t2 = time.time()
    print 'Math: %.3f, Sympy: %.3f' % (t1-t0, t2-t1)
```

And some tests.

```
>>> benchmark(512)
Math: 0.001, Sympy: 0.241
>>> benchmark(2003)
Math: 3.852, Sympy: 41.695
```

We know that 512 is not a prime. The very second term we have to check for divisibility fails the test, so most of the time is actually spent generating the coefficients. Python lazily computes them while sympy must expand the whole polynomial out before we can start collecting them. This shows as that a generator approach is preferable.

2003 is prime and here we notice sympy performs 10 times as slowly. In fact, all of the time is spent generating the coefficients, as iterating over 2000 elements for a modulo operation takes no time. So if there are any further optimisations, that's where one should focus.

#### numpy.poly1d()

Numpy has a class that can manipulate polynomial coefficients and it's exactly what we want. It even works relatively fast for powers up to 50k. However, in its original implementation it's useless to us. That is because the coefficients are stored as signed int32, which means very quickly they will overflow and our modulo operations will be thrown off. In fact, it'll fail for even 37.

But it's fast, though, right? Maybe if we can hack it so it accepts infite precision integers... Maybe it's possible, maybe it isn't. But even if it is, we have to consider that maybe the reason why it is so fast is exactly because it uses a fixed precision type under the hood.

For the sake of curiosity, this is what the implementation would look like if it were any useful.

```
import numpy as np

def is_prime_numpy(p):
    poly = pow(np.poly1d([1, -1]), p)
    return not any(c % p for c in poly.coeffs[1:-1])
```

And for the curious ones, the source code is located in [...\numpy\lib\polynomial.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/polynomial.py).

Comment: as side note, you don't need the whole pascal's triangle, only the first half because it is symmetric

Comment: also the combinatoric number is always a Natural number, so you can use integer division `//` without problem and eliminate the need of cast to int the resulting float or the inexact result you will get in larger numbers

Comment: in that case why the `int(...)` ? (also `//` is valid in python 2)

Comment: @Copperfield Well, that's embarrassing! I copied the formula from an old file I had. Yes, `int()` needs to go. And it's because I was using Python 3's division operator. In retrospect, having the `//` regardless doesn't hurt at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood what you mean, but for checking if a number is an integer or float you can use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
>>> isinstance(1/2.0, float)
>>> True
>>> isinstance(1/2, float)
>>> False
```

Comment: Actually, what the OP is asking is to check for divisibility of all coefficients of a polynomial.

Comment: Thankyou so much everyone, i Will try that.